# Overwrite Scheme on Delta Live Tables workflow

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I am new to Delta Live Tables and have been working with a relatively simple pipeline.

The table that I am having an issue is as follows:

```py
@dlt.table(
    table_properties={ "quality" : "silver" }
)
def silver_catalog_product():
    
    eav_attributes = dlt.read("eav_attribute");
    
    entityDf = dlt.read("product_entity")   
    
    entity_datetime_Df = dlt.read("product_entity_datetime")  
    entity_datetime_Df = entity_datetime_Df.join(eav_attributes,entity_datetime_Df.attribute_id ==  eav_attributes.attribute_id,"inner")
    entity_datetime_Df = entity_datetime_Df.groupBy("entity_id").pivot("attribute_code").agg(first("value"))
    
    df = (entityDf
          .join(entity_datetime_Df, entityDf.entity_id == entity_datetime_Df.entity_id, "inner")
          .drop(entity_datetime_Df.entity_id)
     )
    
    return df
```

However, when the pipeline runs I get the following error:

```
To enable schema migration using DataFrameWriter or DataStreamWriter, please set:
'.option("mergeSchema", "true")'.
For other operations, set the session configuration
spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled to "true". See the documentation
specific to the operation for details.

Table schema:
root
-- entity_id: long (nullable = true)
-- entity_type_id: integer (nullable = true)
-- attribute_set_id: integer (nullable = true)
-- type_id: string (nullable = true)
-- sku: string (nullable = true)
-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- has_options: integer (nullable = true)
-- required_options: integer (nullable = true)


Data schema:
root
-- entity_id: long (nullable = true)
-- entity_type_id: integer (nullable = true)
-- attribute_set_id: integer (nullable = true)
-- type_id: string (nullable = true)
-- sku: string (nullable = true)
-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- has_options: integer (nullable = true)
-- required_options: integer (nullable = true)
-- custom_design_from: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- custom_design_to: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- news_from_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- news_to_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- price_update_type_revert_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- special_from_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- special_to_date: timestamp (nullable = true)

         
To overwrite your schema or change partitioning, please set:
'.option("overwriteSchema", "true")'.

Note that the schema can't be overwritten when using
'replaceWhere'.
```

I have two main questions.

1. The suggestions indicate `.option("overwriteSchema", "true")` or `.option("mergeSchema", "true")`. I am familiar with these options in a regular Delta pyspark job but
   I have no idea, nor can I find any documentation on how to enable
   'overwriteSchema' in Delta Live Tables.
2. Why is the job inferring the schema as the `entityDf` table and not the actual dataframe `df` being returned in the query?

Comment: Hmmm, DLT should have mergeSchema enabled... What channel is used? `current`?

Comment: @AlexOtt I haven't selected any preview features and I see no mention of preview so I can only assume it's the stable/current release.

The workspace was created from their tooling to an AWS backplane.

Comment: Yes I can confirm channel is set to Current

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find a way around it, other than deleting the dlt data (system, events) in storage, @Oliver?

Comment: I haven't and got shunted to ask the Databricks community with no feedback from our databricks representative. Unfortunately, other things came up and I never carried on trying to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: We are having exact same issue with DLTs. Did anyone have any luck with it?

Comment: This error occurs when you trying to write with a different schema.  Just remember that the name of your table will be the name of the function as you haven't defined the name parameter.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?